# House davit? Do they exist?

Tags: materials, ladder

On boats there is a often a boom with a winch called a "davit". It is essentially a sort of crane that allows things to be loaded on and off the boat.

Houses do not seem to normally have davits, even though it might be useful in getting heavy objects like furniture, boxes of books, or other materials to a 2nd or 3rd floor.

The closest thing I have seen are the hoists barns have to get bales of hay to the loft.

Why not have one for a house? I would think you could even make a removable hoist. In other words, there would just be a socket, and the beam would go in the socket when the hoist was needed, then you could remove it and put it away when not in use.

Comment: I constructed a removable davit on my three-story house. I use it to move furniture to and from my first-story or second-story deck, whence I wheel it in or out of the house. - I had to make the davit removable because it interferes with an attic window. - If you build one, be sure to attach it to a sufficiently strong part of the house.

Comment: They are common in old canal-side houses in Amsterdam!

Comment: The barn bale-lifters are an extension of the main beam of the barn.    I can't honestly see any builder, least of all in the USA, adding that feature since it would create long term liability for them when someone got hurt. Simple fact is furniture isn't made to be hoisted. Another way to go is rent a reach forklift...